# Why does unsigned++ not loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a multiplication program with beq, add, nand. This code works but I don't understand how this code exits the loop since the test value is always adding it self. Thank you for advice. (I'm using goto and label because I will make this code into mips assembly later).

```
unsigned mult(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
  unsigned test = 1, ans = 0;
next:
  if ((test & x) == 0) goto skip;
  ans += y;
skip: 
  y += y;
  test += test;
  if (test != 0) goto next;
  return ans; 
}
```

Comment: There are places and situations where `goto` and labels are okay to use. Instead of loops is not one of those.

Comment: I do  not rule out that this was written like this on purpose (to make it work and look like the equivalent assembler code).

Comment: I'll make this code into mips assembly later. That is why I write it this way.

Comment: @Boiethios Thanks , I will do that.

Comment: Replace test += test with test <<= 1 for a more readable program.

Comment: And before someone asks: @dasblinkenlight's suggested change should have no performance impact. If it does, use a better compiler.

Comment: @Rhymoid It depends on the microcontroller that is used. If it has a left shift instruction what you say is correct. Some very low end microcontrollers do not have a shift instruction, e.g. PIC12

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Uhm... if the compiler has to implement shifts as self-additions, there simply is no performance impact if you move from `test += test` to `test <<= 1`. Shifts are more readable in this particular case, and that's all what counts. Besides, you can implement a left-shift instruction in PIC12 using RLC and a carry clearing instruction (e.g. ADDLW 0).

Comment: @Rhymoid The PIC12 can add in one instruction by using a `ADDWF f,d` instruction.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje It's not self-addition unless you do `MOVF f, 0 ; ADDWF f, 1`. My suggestion `ADDLW 0 ; RLC f, 1` takes the same amount of cycles and does not seem to clobber `W`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` will roll over and then the value will be 0.

`test` will take on the values `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 ,.... 2147483648 , 0`

The logic of the code is interesting,

It checks if the LSbit of `x` is 1. If yes, it adds `y` to the answer.

If the next LSbit of `x` it will add `2*y` to the answer.

For each bit of `x` that is 1 it will add `2^n*y`, giving the final answer.